# Intersections of Circles in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to have my agent move to a random position inside the intersection of a number of circles.
I am trying to achieve this by positions (retrieving the list of positions for each circle, getting the positions that are in the intersection, then have the agent move to a random position inside the intersection.)
What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know any neat formula for the lens-shaped area of intersection of two circles so here's what I'd call an acceptable punt.   Anything in the intersection has to be within the first circle's radius of the center of it,  and also has to be within the second circle's radius of it's center.    So if you just generate a sequence of random test points  and check for whether both of those things are true,  the first "hit" you get will, voila,  be a random point in your intersection area.

You can use the Pythagorean formula to find a distance, or with even less math you can just put a turtle at the center of each circle and ask Netlogo the distance from your test point to that agent  ( ie, use "distance agent" or "distance x y" .

Oh -- and if the circles are too far apart there won't be any intersection at all, so don't go looking for it.

Here's code that does a crude job of drawing two circles and solving the problem. You get the idea.    I keep going after the first hit to draw out the lens-shaped area to visually confirm that this is working, but you would stop at the first hit.

I draw the circles just to confirm this is doing what I think it's doing.  You don't need to draw the circles and can skip all that.

Oh I don't know what you want to do about world-wrap-around.  That's your call.

```
;; globals [ r1 x1 y1 r2 x2 y2 ] by sliders
turtles-own [ fake ]

to setup
  clear-all
   draw-circle x1 y1 r1 green
   draw-circle x2 y2 r2 blue
  reset-ticks
end

to go

  draw-circle x1 y1 r1 green
  draw-circle x2 y2 r2 blue

  ifelse  sqrt((x1 - x2)*(x1 - x2)  + ( y1 - y2 )*(y1 - y2))  >=  ( r1 + r2 )
    [ print " Circles too far apart, so there is no intersection " stop ]
  [ repeat 3 [
           let x max-pxcor - random (  max-pxcor - min-pxcor )
           let y max-pycor - random (  max-pycor - min-pycor )
           let dist1   sqrt((x1 - x )*(x1 - x )  + ( y1 - y  )*(y1 - y ))
           let dist2  sqrt((x2 - x )*(x2 - x )  + ( y2 - y  )*(y2 - y ))
           if  (( dist1  < r1 ) and ( dist2 < r2 ))
              [ ask patch x y [ set pcolor red ]]
  ]]

  reset-ticks
end


to draw-circle [ x y r shade ]
   create-turtles 1 [setxy ( x +  r ) y set color shade pen-down set heading 0 set fake true domove r]
end

to domove [ radius ]
  repeat 100 [fd 1 set heading ( heading -  ( 59 / radius)    ) ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually found a cleaner way to do this.  1) setup the viable patches to be all patches 2) create the circles 3) iterate over the circles and setup the viable patches to be what was a viable patch and is inside the circle 4) after the loop move to one of the viable patches